# Apollo GraphQL: Calling a Query Twice with apolloClient.query?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have the following query:

```
const GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY = gql`
query($userID: String!){
  myUserDataForIMs(userID:userID){
    name_first
    name_last
    picture_medium
  }
} `;

const withUserInfoForIMs = graphql(GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY, {
    options({ userID }) {
        return {
            variables: { userID: `${userID}`}
        };
    }
    ,
    props({ data: { loading, myUserDataForIMs } }) {
        return { loading, myUserDataForIMs };
    },
    name: 'GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY',
});
```

From the [Apollo docs](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862#.3a9qmd8x1), it looks like I may be able to call this query twice from inside the component, using apolloClient.query, doing something like this:

```
client.query({ query: query1 })
client.query({ query: query2 })
```

Is there a way to call the query twice, passing a different userID each time?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. :)

```
        const localThis = this;
        this.props.ApolloClientWithSubscribeEnabled.query({
            query: GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY,
            variables: {userID: fromID},
        }).then((result) => {
            localThis.setState({ fromAvatar: result.data.myUserDataForIMs[0].picture_thumbnail });
        });

        this.props.ApolloClientWithSubscribeEnabled.query({
            query: GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY,
            variables: {userID: toID},
        }).then((result) => {
             localThis.setState({ toAvatar: result.data.myUserDataForIMs[0].picture_thumbnail });
        });
```

If there's a better/more efficient way, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing Apollo's `refetch()` method into your component's props alongside the data:

```
const withUserInfoForIMs = graphql(GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY, {
    options({ userID }) {
        return {
            variables: { userID: `${userID}`}
        };
    },
    props({ data: { refetch, loading, myUserDataForIMs } }) {
        return { refetch, loading, myUserDataForIMs };
    },
    name: 'GET_MY_USERINFOFORIMS_QUERY',
});
```

...then somewhere in your component, you can refetch the data "manually":

```
theUserWasChangedSomehow(userID) {
  this.props.refetch({ userID });
}
```